# getting error while using tcp.dport in dpkt

Tags: python, pcap

Im trying to parse the recorded PCAP file using dpkt of python. when i tried to filter tcp connections which is having http(on port 80) requests, I'm getting error as follows ::`

```
import dpkt
import socket
counter=0
ipcounter=0
tcpcounter=0
udpcounter=0
httpcounter=0

filename='sampledata.pcap'

for ts, pkt in dpkt.pcap.Reader(file(filename, "rb")):

    counter+=1
    eth=dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(pkt) 
    if eth.type!=dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP:
       continue

    ip=eth.data
    tcp=ip.data
    ipcounter+=1

    if ip.p==dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_TCP: 
       tcpcounter+=1

    if ip.p==dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_UDP:
       udpcounter+=1

    if tcp.dport == 80 and tcp.flags & tcp.TH_SYN == 1 and tcp.flags & tcp.TH_SYN == 1 and tcp.flags & tcp.TH_ACK == 1 :
        src = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.src)
        dst = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.dst)
        print "%s -> %s" %(src,dst)`
```

error:: I am getting some OSPF error as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 72, in <module>
    if tcp.dport == 80 and tcp.flags & tcp.TH_SYN == 1 and tcp.flags & tcp.TH_SYN == 1 and tcp.flags & tcp.TH_ACK == 1 :
AttributeError: 'OSPF' object has no attribute 'dport'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that the data encapsulated in the IP packet is tcp. But in this case, it is an OSPF packet. OSPF does not use a TCP/IP transport protocol (UDP, TCP), but is encapsulated directly in IP datagrams with protocol number 89.

You need to check the protocol type in the packet, and if it is tcp or udp then use the dport.

```
# Include the following condition in your for loop
if ip.p not in (dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_TCP, dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_UDP):
    continue
```

Comment: tanks..but now its showing error at tcp.TH_SYN as follows:  **AttributeError: 'TCP' object has no attribute 'TH_SYN'**

Comment: It should be `tcp.flags & dpkt.tcp.TH_SYN == 1`